# Rails 3.2 and Remotipart not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, remotipart

I have remotipart in my gem file:

```
gem 'remotipart',:require=>'remotipart'
```

and is not in a group

On the development remote uploading with remotipart 1.2.1 works with no issue:

```
<%= form_tag upload_gallery_image_path, :remote => true do  %> 
<%= file_field_tag 'image', :accept => %w(image/png image/jpeg image/bmp image/gif image/x-xbitmap image/bmp) %>
<%= submit_tag 'upload'%>
```

produces this:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zrJLp+YwjSR8TjmJeQS8JQnLtJU9o9ZJ9JKeADSMuDI=", "commit"=>"upload", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5cfbdec740 @original_filename="dragon.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"dragon.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130730-7136-drtbwz>>}
```

I have this debugging statement in:

```
if remotipart_submitted?
  puts 'yes'
else
 puts 'no'
end
```

It prints yes, and paperclip does it thing.

In production the debugging statement prints no and the parameters are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NW7HCQXZHRuqnS22ar/h8T6Vu1wTtN9fYm63ZJbpnRU=", "image"=>"dragon.jpg", "commit"=>"upload"}
```

and paperclip predictably chokes on that since no image is upload.

Yes remotipart is installed on the server and it seems everything got loaded because `remotipart_submitted?` is defined.

Comment: If you got this working, I'd love to know how. My difference is, paperclip say it's saving attachments, but nothing gets saved, and the database record the image is attached to gets created, with nil values for the file info. Very confusing.